# An ice cream parlor has n toppings.

Tags: combinatorics

An ice cream parlor has n toppings.

(a) How many i-topping ice cream cones are possible, where i = 0, . . . , n?

(b) Considering that an ice cream cone can have anywhere from 0 to n toppings, derive a formula for the total number of ice cream cones possible.

(c) We can also count the number of possible ice cream cones by considering each topping to be an experiment with two outcomes: on or off. Use the GBPC to determine the number of ice cream cones possible in this way.

(d) Equate your answers from parts (b) and (c) to derive an interesting identity involving binomial
coefficients. (This identity can also be derived by setting x = y = 1 in the binomial theorem and
has a neat implication for the sums of rows of Pascal’s triangle.)

I'm confused on the entirety of this problem, anything helps! Thank you!

For (a) I need a formula for how many possible i-toppings ice cream cones there are. We have to assume we can't double up on toppings. I have $\frac{n!}{2x}$. I don't think this is correct.

For (b) Would it be i=x, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore the outcomes goes from 0 to n?

For (c) and (d) I have no attempt.

Comment: Hint for (d): $(1+1)^n = 2^n$.  This is a combinatorics question rather than a probability question

Comment: Your "attempt" for (a) has an $x$ in the answer... but $x$ does not appear in the problem.  Perhaps you meant $i$ instead?  Even then, this will be wrong.  Consider what a binomial coefficient might be useful for here.

Comment: Does the basic formula work, $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: $k$ doesn't appear in the question either

Comment: $\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$

Comment: Good... but we need to make sure you are understanding *why* this might be the answer.  Other than the fact that it was heavily hinted that it would be useful here, in your own words can you explain why it is used here?  What does a binomial coefficient like this count?  Once you are done with that and ready to move on to part (b), we are trying to count all ways we could have chosen some collection of toppings.  As you allude to, we are able to choose $0$ toppings or $1$ topping or $2$ toppings, etc... so maybe a summation of something will happen here...

Comment: For (c), whatever your book called "GBPC" is likely the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  For the first topping option we either do or don't include it on our icecream (2 options).  For the second topping we either do or don't include it on our icecream (2 options).  Continue in this fashion.  Apply rule of product and reach a conclusion on how many ways there were to include or not each of the toppings.  For (d) recognize that our answers for (b) and (c) were both answers to the same question, just arrived at in different ways, and so expressions must be equal

Comment: For (a) since were trying to select a group of i from n possibilities, we have a combination, so therefore we can use the definition of a combination to solve our answer. For (b) if we use a summation, would it be the formula for the Binomial Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) There are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to select a subset of $i$ of the toppings to use, seen directly by the definition of what a binomial coefficient represents.

(b) Summing over all possible amounts of toppings that we could have selected, there are $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}$ total ways in which we could have selected some subset of toppings regardless of size

(c) Utilizing rule of product, noting that for each topping we either use or don't use the topping, we see that there are $2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2 = 2^n$ total ways in which we could have selected some subset of toppings regardless of size

(d) We recognize that (b) and (c) both answer the same question and so their answers must be equal even if they appear different, thus we learn that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$